# Hide a toggle whenever I click outside the menu or click on any menu item using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have created a toggle window on the left side of a web page. I want to hide the toggle window whenever I click on any anchor tag in a menu or click outside the menu bar.

I have uploaded my code in JSFiddle. The relevant code is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/66db9vec/

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
        var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
        $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. The script basically checks if clicked element is the toggle icon and toggles the class, if its not - it removes it (not toggling again to avoid showing up the menu when not intended).

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var toggle_el = $("[data-toggle]");
    var container = $("[data-toggle]").data("toggle");

    if (!toggle_el.is(e.target)) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    {        
        if($(container).hasClass("open-sidebar")) {
            $(container).removeClass("open-sidebar"); 
        }
    }
    else {
        $(container).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have one more issue with this.
it is not working on iframe.
How do i solve this...??

Comment: You're welcome! Could you explain a bit more in what context are you using the iframe?

Comment: am using iframe in the same page and it is not working when i click on iframe.
see this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/66db9vec/4/

Comment: It's tricky to work with events on iframes but you can get use of jQuery method called .contents(), that when used on an iframe element returns the document of the iframe. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66db9vec/8/